# Training a sklearn LogisticRegression classifier without all possible labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use scikit-learn 0.12.1 to:

1. train a LogisticRegression classifier
2. evaluate the classifer on held out validation data
3. feed new data to this classifier and retrieve the 5 most probable labels for each observation

Sklearn makes all of this very easy except for one peculiarity. There is no guarantee that every possible label will occur in the data used to fit my classifier. There are hundreds of possible labels and some of them have not occurred in the training data available.

This results in 2 problems:

1. The label vectorizer doesn't recognize previously unseen labels when they occur in the validation data. This is easily fixed by fitting the labeler to the set of possible labels but it exacerbates problem 2.
2. The output of the predict_proba method of the LogisticRegression classifier is an [n_samples, n_classes] array, where n_classes consists *only* of the classes seen in the training data. This means running argsort on the predict_proba array no longer provides values that directly map to the label vectorizer's vocabulary.

My question is, what's the best way to force the classifier to recognize the full set of possible classes, even when some of them don't occur in the training data? Obviously it will have trouble learning about labels it has never seen data for, but 0's are perfectly useable in my situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a workaround. Make sure you have a list of all classes called `all_classes`. Then, if `clf` is your `LogisticRegression` classifier,

```
from itertools import repeat

# determine the classes that were not present in the training set;
# the ones that were are listed in clf.classes_.
classes_not_trained = set(clf.classes_).symmetric_difference(all_classes)

# the order of classes in predict_proba's output matches that in clf.classes_.
prob = clf.predict_proba(test_samples)
for row in prob:
    prob_per_class = (zip(clf.classes_, prob)
                    + zip(classes_not_trained, repeat(0.)))
```

produces a list of `(cls, prob)` pairs.

Comment: Much more elegant than the work around I was using. Is the classes_ attribute intended to be present in all sklearn classifiers? In 0.12.1 LogisticRegression only has label_ but this appears to change in later versions.

Comment: @AlexanderMeasure: yes, `classes_` should be present on all classifiers, but it presently isn't -- this is a known bug that is fixed on a per-class basis. 0.13 has `classes_` on LR, I'd forgotten that 0.12.1 did not yet have it.

Comment: Oops, this doesn't quite work. clf.predict_proba returns an array of shape [n_samples, n_clf_classes]. The array iterates across rows so zipping it with classes results in the class zipped to an n_clf_classes length array of probabilities from a test sample, which isn't particularly useful. It works if we zip the classes to each row however.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is an array like that returned by `predict_proba`, but with columns corresponding to sorted `all_classes`, how about:

```
all_classes = numpy.array(sorted(all_classes))
# Get the probabilities for learnt classes
prob = clf.predict_proba(test_samples)
# Create the result matrix, where all values are initially zero
new_prob = numpy.zeros((prob.shape[0], all_classes.size))
# Set the columns corresponding to clf.classes_
new_prob[:, all_classes.searchsorted(clf.classes_)] = prob
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on larsman's excellent answer, I ended up with this:

```
from itertools import repeat
import numpy as np

# determine the classes that were not present in the training set;
# the ones that were are listed in clf.classes_.
classes_not_trained = set(clf.classes_).symmetric_difference(all_classes)

# the order of classes in predict_proba's output matches that in clf.classes_.
prob = clf.predict_proba(test_samples)
new_prob = []
for row in prob:
    prob_per_class = zip(clf.classes_, prob) + zip(classes_not_trained, repeat(0.))
    # put the probabilities in class order
    prob_per_class = sorted(prob_per_class)
    new_prob.append(i[1] for i in prob_per_class)
new_prob = np.asarray(new_prob)
```

new_prob is an [n_samples, n_classes] array just like the output from predict_proba, except now it includes 0 probabilities for the previously unseen classes.